# Could Functions for Firebase invocations displayed in Stackdriver

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, stackdriver

I'm using Firebase with Cloud Functions on the Blaze plan, and I would like to get an overview of how many of the 2 million free monthly invocations I'm using. After that (that's another story though) I would like to make the same overview for the other price points that Firebase is billing for, such as GB-seconds, CPU-seconds, and Network Outbound usage. I can't see these metrics in the firebase console, so my approach is to use the Google Cloud Console and Stackdriver.

**Function Invocations in Firebase**

[image: Function Invocations in Firebase console]

**Function Executions in Stackdriver**

[image: Function Executions in Stackdriver]

As it's seen on the two graphs, they clearly have the same shape, but the scales are different. The Firebase graph appears to have 3-4-times larger magnitudes that the Stackdriver graph.

**Questions:**

- How come the two graph doesn't match each other?
- Which one am I being billed for?

Here is how I've configured the Stackdriver chart:

[image: Cloud functions executions sum chart in stackdriver]

Comment: You should contact Firebase support directly if you find problems with the Firebase console and billing issues.   https://firebase.google.com/support/

Comment: Okay, I've forwarded my questions to them.. My guess is that they'll say "You are being billed for the Firebase Graph", and can't answer my first problem, because it isn't a Firebase Billing issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I asked the Firebase Support Team as Doug proposed.

Here's what they replied:

> I just got an update from our engineers.
>
> They're hinting that the difference might come from the aligner being
>   count and not sum, which is what the Firebase Console uses. With this,
>   could you try changing it and see if the values change?
>
> Additionally, the console is pulling the data from Stackdriver, so the
>   source of the data should be the same. You should also be billed based
>   on the Stackdriver values. If there's still a discrepancy, please let
>   me know and provide the updated screenshots so I can investigate
>   further.

Afterwards I changed the aligner to be `sum` instead of `count`, which resultet in a chart with roughly the same scale as the Firebase graph.

**So to answer my own questions:**

> How come the two graph doesn't match each other?

The should! The aligner in the Stackdriver chart must the set to `sum` to reflect the Firebase graph.

> Which one am I being billed for?

Both! The data in Firebase originates from Stackdriver, so the graphs should match. If they don't It's likely an issue with the Stackdriver chart settings, and Firebase must be the true value.